# Automatic download Testflight builds on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, continuous-integration, testflight

Is a there a way to have my iPhone/iPad automatically download builds from Testflight as they become available?

I already automated the rest of the building process, and when I update a bunch of apps I feel kind of silly for having to go through the Testflight app (a webpage) and individually clicking all the apps I just updated and choosing to download them.

I would also like to know if there is such a solution for android.

Comment: now iOS have features in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Are you talking about receiving emails to test builds? Other than that I can't find anywhere in the GUI where that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something that automatically downloads, installs, and updates builds. You'll want to go with a Mobile Device Management vendor; such as my product [AppBlade](http://appblade.com).

We are given remote access to iOS/OSX devices via an API that Apple exposes to us; and installation can be triggered in browser or via APIS. On Android we have an AppStore application in beta.